# Exporting default and arguments at the same time

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

This is the way I'd like to consume my lib:

```
import MyLib, { factory, fn1, fn2 } from "mylib";

console.log(MyLib, MyLib.fn1 === fn1) // { factory, fn1, fn2 } true
const MyLib2 = factory() // this just create another instance of MyLib
```

This is how I'd like to export it

```
function factory() {
  return {
    factory, fn1, fn2
  }
}

const MyLib = factory()
export default MyLib
```

But this is how I actually have to do it:

```
function factory() {
  return {
      factory, fn1, fn2
  }
}

const MyLib = factory()
const { fn1, fn2 } = MyLib

export default MyLib
export { factory, fn1, fn2 }
```

If I add fn3 I have to write it in three places. Is there a way to export in a less verbose way? Like everything that factory returns is what I want to export.

Comment: Why are `fn1` and `fn2` created within your factory? They're supposed to be exported as standalones, no?

Comment: And why does the factory return itself?

Comment: Is a way of dependency injection. I pass parameters to factory.

Comment: Uh, no, in the code you posted you don't pass any parameters to `facory`? And even if you did, that doesn't answer the question why you return `factory` as a part of the object that `factory()` creates.

Comment: I don't get why is that relevant for the question I'm asking. This is the real code https://github.com/DistributedObjectProtocol/dop/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: Ah ok, in that code most the methods on the object that the factory returns are actual stateful and close over the contents - except for the `factory().factory` method.

Comment: As a (slightly opinionated) structure that seems to be better suited to your case, I would recommend: use two modules - one that default-exports the `factory` function itself, and a singleton module that creates one object and then exports its components by name. No, there's no shorter way for this than what you are already doing. The questionable thing that is the source of these problem is the module that acts as a singleton. If you *really* need that, there's no way around repetition. You might consider dropping it altogether though.